# all possible combinations within subset, multicolumn

Tags: r, excel, combinations, vba

Looking for some help to create script for Excel to generate all possible combinations of data. Here is an example of what I have and what I am looking for. ID is the subset identification number, and AID is the participant in that subset.

```
ID  AID
 1   30
 1   52
 1   10
 1   20
 2   10
 2   11
 2   50
```

Need:

```
ID  AID  AID1
 1   30   52
 1   30   10
 1   30   20
 1   52   10
 1   52   20
 1   10   20
 2   10   11
 2   10   50
 2   11   50
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Looking to do this in Excel, but R would work as well. Thanks!!

Comment: What exactly is AID1, i.e. what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Please read about cross join in Excel. You cna find a code on the net easily or get some extra addins.

Answer (score 1):

doesn't look like you actually have ALL combinations. Have you considered using SQL to solve your problem? you can use the package sqldf in R to do this, and cross join the data with itself.  This gives all combinations:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select a.ID, a.AID, b.AID AID1
       FROM data a 
       JOIN data b ON a.ID = b.ID")
```

and this gives the output shown in the question:

```
sqldf("select a.ID, a.AID, b.AID AID1
       FROM data a 
       JOIN data b ON a.ID = b.ID and a.rowid < b.rowid")
```

Comment: Thanks guys. This one work really well. I did put it to a new data table, as number of obs topped out at 3500 on my console. All in all, 12K obs now done. Easy! Thanks again!

Comment: Can you please vote for helpful answers and tick the correct one? thanks

Comment: unfortunately my rep isn't strong enough for me to up vote. That said, this suggestion worked the best for me. The second code was the one I used, as I wanted to eventually pairwise.

Answer (score 0):

```
dat <- read.table(text="
ID  AID
1   30
1   52
1   10
1   20
2   10
2   11
2   50",sep="",header=TRUE)


res <- do.call(rbind,lapply(split(dat, dat$ID), function(x)    {setNames(data.frame(x$ID[1], t(combn(x$AID,2))),c("ID", paste0("AID",c("",1))))}))
row.names(res) <- 1:nrow(res)
```

One possibility to have that error would be:

```
dat <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), AID = c(30L, 52L, 
10L, 20L, 1L)), .Names = c("ID", "AID"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

lapply(split(dat,dat$ID),function(x) combn(x$AID,2))
#Error in combn(x$AID, 2) : n < m

res <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(dat, dat$ID), function(x) {
if (length(x$AID) > 1) 
    setNames(data.frame(x$ID[1], t(combn(x$AID, 2))), c("ID", paste0("AID", c("", 
        1)))) else transform(x, AID1 = AID)
}))

row.names(res) <- 1:nrow(res)
```

Comment: Mine is not text, but a csv file imported to R. This error when using this method: Error in combn(x$AID, 2) : n < m

Comment: Please show a small example data (that produce the error) using ?dput()

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method somewhat similar to that of Guest, but using `by` to split by ID.

```
z <- by(x$AID, x$ID, function(i) if(length(i)>1) combn(i,2) else NULL)
do.call(rbind, lapply(names(z), 
        function(i) if (is.null(z[[i]])) NULL else data.frame(ID=i, t(z[[i]])))
)
##   ID X1 X2
## 1  1 30 52
## 2  1 30 10
## 3  1 30 20
## 4  1 52 10
## 5  1 52 20
## 6  1 10 20
## 7  2 10 11
## 8  2 10 50
## 9  2 11 50
```

Set names as appropriate.

`NULL` is used returned in the function passed to `by` so that it can be filtered in the `lapply` expression.  `rbind` ignores `NULL` inputs.